# Redirecting Views dynamically generated URL's via .htaccess RewriteRule - CSS stylehseets arent loading after change

Tags: views, redirection, .htaccess

I have many dynamically generated pages via views and it seems the easiest way to redirect them is using the .htaccess file via a **RewriteRule**. I put in the following right above the index.php rewriterule and none of the css files are loading anymore. obviously i have something wrong here, but what?

Doesn't the first rewrite fire only if it detects the **buy** string in the first part of the url? I dont see how that would interfere with anything.

```
RewriteRule ^buy(/?.*) http://www.EXAMPLE.com/buy$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

actually i put the RewriteRule above the RewriteCond and it seems to be working good now. so it seems that RewriteCond corresponds to the RewriteRule that's right below it only like an inline if statement